# ¿Como hacer un calendario de dias habiles y disponibles enlazado a una base de datos con datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Me dejaron un calendario en angular que diera días hábiles y disponibles en una base, vi que esta herramienta ayuda, pero no se como enlazarla, y no me doy idea de como hacerlo, no se, si se pueda hacer con esta.

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - onSelect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate:0,
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function (date) {
    alert(date)
    },
    });
        
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    Fecha:
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Localize calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/datepicker-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/datepicker-he.js"></script>
  <script src="i18n/datepicker-zh-TW.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).on( "change", function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;
  <select id="locale">
    <option value="ar">Arabic (&#8235;(&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;</option>
    <option value="zh-TW">Chinese Traditional (&#32321;&#39636;&#20013;&#25991;)</option>
    <option value="">English</option>
    <option value="fr" selected="selected">French (Fran&ccedil;ais)</option>
    <option value="he">Hebrew (&#8235;(&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;&#1497;&#1514;</option>
  </select></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Esto lo extraje directamente de la documentacion de jquery datepicker, de igual manera te dejo el enlace porque puedes realizar diferentes configuracion segun lo que requieras.
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default